# Can't Add a New Fee to an Existing Event in 4.7.20

Tags: civievent

I have created an event with several payment options and it works properly with no issues. However, when adding a new fee (there are 5 at the moment that works), It doesn't get saved and the loader spinner just spins forever.

Underneath, when inspecting the network when the form is submitted, I get this

> {status: "fatal",…} content : "Sorry but we are not
>   able to provide this at the moment." crmMessages : [{,…}] 0 :
>   {,…} options : null text : "We experienced an unexpected error. Please
>   post a detailed description and the backtrace on the CiviCRM forums:
>   http://forum.civicrm.org/" title : "Sorry an error occurred" type :
>   "error" status : "fatal" title : "Configure Event - B1
>   Course" userContext : "/civicrm/event/manage?reset=1"

In the error logs, this detailed response is outputted:

```
There was a CiviCRM error at ISKCON London Ltd.
Date: 2017-06-11T12:52:30+01:00



***ERROR***
message:            
code:                

***LAST ERROR***


***LOGGED IN USER***
contact_id:         2
display_name:       Mr. Aashish Sharma
email_id:           
email:              
id:                 2

REMOTE_ADDR: 82.47.150.10
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36


***SERVER***
PATH:               /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
REDIRECT_STATUS:    200
UNIQUE_ID:          WT0u-sMI3iEAABks7HYAAABJ
TZ:                 Europe/Sofia
OMP_THREAD_LIMIT:   1
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: 
HTTPS:              on
SSL_TLS_SNI:        rldb.info
HTTP_HOST:          rldb.info
HTTP_CONNECTION:    keep-alive
CONTENT_LENGTH:     8826
HTTP_ORIGIN:        https://rldb.info
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
CONTENT_TYPE:       multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxVzJBFAoBtR543ba
HTTP_ACCEPT:        application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:XMLHttpRequest
HTTP_DNT:           1
HTTP_REFERER:       https://rldb.info/civicrm/event/manage/fee?reset=1&action=update&id=48
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
HTTP_COOKIE:        SESSfdfbbafa8321456c2612c2aa8f3eb683=UM-Iryeyj-zQpNIzlWLda-cQEovuWWEBLfp_RW-LN-E; Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; SSESSfdfbbafa8321456c2612c2aa8f3eb683=cOvpS0HYROxslVL4qewR4nCYYYg8VRpQZUmtSDA2Oik; has_js=1
SERVER_SIGNATURE:   
SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache
SERVER_NAME:        rldb.info
SERVER_ADDR:        195.8.222.33
SERVER_PORT:        443
REMOTE_ADDR:        82.47.150.10
DOCUMENT_ROOT:      /home/rldb/www/www
REQUEST_SCHEME:     https
CONTEXT_PREFIX:     
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/home/rldb/www/www
SERVER_ADMIN:       admin@rldb.info
SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /home/rldb/www/www/index.php
REMOTE_PORT:        60253
REDIRECT_URL:       /civicrm/event/manage/fee
REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING:action=update&id=48&component=event&qfKey=8597fbacd761cbef1573e2c09b4cf85a_3956&snippet=json
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD:     POST
QUERY_STRING:       action=update&id=48&component=event&qfKey=8597fbacd761cbef1573e2c09b4cf85a_3956&snippet=json
REQUEST_URI:        /civicrm/event/manage/fee?action=update&id=48&component=event&qfKey=8597fbacd761cbef1573e2c09b4cf85a_3956&snippet=json
SCRIPT_NAME:        /index.php
PHP_SELF:           /index.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1497181950.1148
REQUEST_TIME:       1497181950
argv:               Array
(
    [0] => action=update&id=48&component=event&qfKey=8597fbacd761cbef1573e2c09b4cf85a_3956&snippet=json
)

argc:               1



***BACKTRACE***
#0 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php(251): reporterror_civicrm_generatereport("ISKCON London Ltd", (Array:2), NULL, (Array:0))
#1 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(365): reporterror_civicrm_handler((Array:2))
#2 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1070): CRM_Core_Error::fatal()
#3 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceFieldValue.php(65): CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue("CRM_Price_BAO_PriceFieldValue", NULL, "price_field_id")
#4 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceFieldValue.php(127): CRM_Price_BAO_PriceFieldValue::add((Array:3), (Array:1))
#5 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceField.php(184): CRM_Price_BAO_PriceFieldValue::create((Array:3), (Array:1))
#6 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent/Fee.php(670): CRM_Price_BAO_PriceField::create((Array:9))
#7 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447): CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee->postProcess()
#8 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(169): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#9 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(136): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee), "upload")
#10 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee), "upload")
#11 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee), "upload")
#12 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")
#13 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#14 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee", "Event Fees", NULL)
#15 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#16 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#17 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#18 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "manage", "fee")
#19 /home/rldb/www/www/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#20 /home/rldb/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#21 {main}


***POST***
qfKey:              8597fbacd761cbef1573e2c09b4cf85a_3956
entryURL:           https://rldb.info/civicrm/event/manage/fee?reset=1&amp;action=update&amp;id=48&amp;component=event&amp;qfKey=8597fbacd761cbef1573e2c09b4cf85a_3956
price_field_id:     168
price_field_value:  Array
(
    [1] => 537
    [2] => 538
    [3] => 539
    [4] => 540
    [5] => 541
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
)

discount_price_set: Array
(
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
)

cancelURL:          /civicrm/event/manage?reset=1
_qf_default:        Fee:upload
MAX_FILE_SIZE:      20971520
is_template:        0
is_monetary:        1
currency:           GBP
payment_processor:  1
pay_later_text:     I will send payment by cheque
pay_later_receipt:  
fee_label:          Event Fee(s)
financial_type_id:  9
price_set_id:       
label:              Array
(
    [1] => For all 6 Units of Bhakti Sastri
    [2] => If spouses/partners do course together. cost per participant
    [3] => Cost for One Unit
    [4] => For Temple Asrama
    [5] => Others - pay in 2 instalments
    [6] => test
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
)

value:              Array
(
    [1] => 275.00
    [2] => 250.00
    [3] => 50.00
    [4] => 0.00
    [5] => 137.50
    [6] => 50.00
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
)

default:            1
discount_name:      Array
(
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
)

discount_start_date:Array
(
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
)

discount_start_date_1_display_593d2e777d8ea:
discount_end_date:  Array
(
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
)

discount_end_date_1_display_593d2e777ef79:
discount_start_date_2_display_593d2e77805c8:
discount_end_date_2_display_593d2e7781c84:
discount_start_date_3_display_593d2e778357c:
discount_end_date_3_display_593d2e7784b4b:
discount_start_date_4_display_593d2e7786147:
discount_end_date_4_display_593d2e7787771:
discount_start_date_5_display_593d2e7788e1e:
discount_end_date_5_display_593d2e778a52b:
_qf_Fee_upload:     Save
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Edit 1:
Upgrading CiviCRM from 4.7.19 to 4.7.20 did not resolve the issue.

Edit 2:
When creating a new event from scratch, I can add as many fee options as I want. But, if I save and then add a new fee, then these errors occur and I can't save.

Any help?

Edit 3:
If I add a new fee (after it has been saved) and instead click on 'save and done', this is th emessage:

> Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity
>   error: Expected to find active frame thrown in
>   /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php
>   on line 107

Comment: I am also experiencing this same issue.  4.7.19

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/tarabnyc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

Comment: Hi Sovereign, look like a bug. Can you reproduce it on the http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ site.

Comment: @kanuk I am able to replicate it on your demo.

I reported the bug at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20729?jql=resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20reporter%20%3D%20currentUser()

The only error I get is  Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Return to home page.

Comment: @sovereign108 were you ever able to find a fix?

Comment: @themak unfortunately not. I just tried to avoid the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Go to `<site>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceField.php` line 179

And to the following condition:

```
elseif (!empty($optionsIds)) {
```

Add another condition for verifying that the **`id` exists and is not `null`**, i.e. you may replace it with:

```
elseif (!empty($optionsIds) && isset($optionsIds['id'])) {
```

---

## Explanation

This simple resolution was due to the investigative work of [Favio Manriquez (JIRA)](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20729?focusedCommentId=104938&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-104938) where he explained the following:

> I was able to confirm this behavior.  When debugging, if you print a
>   stack trace at the Fatal Error location, you don't get a lot of
>   information.  By stepping through the code, I arrived at
>   `CRM_Price_BAO_PriceField::create()`.  I'll try to explain what is
>   causing this error:
>
> - When you go to the configure screen for an Event, and then add a new fee (this doesn't happen for events that use price sets), the for
>     loop goes through all fees, and updates or creates them as necessary. 
>     However, on the first if branch, the `$optionsIds` variable is set, and
>     it is used again on the `elseif` branch at line 179 !!
> - It's only when you add a new Fee, that this `elseif` branch causes problems, because the last id in `$optionsIds` is `NULL` (for the new
>     price that was created on first branch).  This causes a fatal error
>     via `CRM_Core_Error::fatal()` which forces a transaction rollback.
>
> This code change was introduced on this [commit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/1019b2fe8e5e506f34cf338d6e4e77f601b408c4#diff-03753662a69aab9f4543e6a8492d2e64R173) for [CRM-19517](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19517), but
>   on previous versions the `elseif` branch is not present, so I'm not
>   exactly sure why this code is needed.
>
> I could add an easy PR to check if the id is `null`, but since this is
>   related to [CRM-19517](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19517), I would like to get more insight first.

As Favio explained, the `null` check is necessary because inside the `elseif` the value of `$optionsIds['id']` is used:

```
 $optionsLoad = civicrm_api3('price_field_value', 'get', array('id' => $optionsIds['id']));
```

1. If `$optionsIds['id']` is `null`, invoking:

   `$options = $optionsLoad['values'][$optionsIds['id']]`

   Would be equivalent to invoke:

   `$options = $optionsLoad['values'][null]`

   Which would only trigger an "undefined index" notice (not stopping the execution).
2. This would in turn provide `null` in `$options`, which are used later in:
     `CRM_Price_BAO_PriceFieldValue::create($options, $optionsIds);`
3. Therefore the `create` is attempted with invalid options and that is why the *Stacktrace* starts with:

   > CRM/Price/BAO/PriceFieldValue.php(65): `CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue("CRM_Price_BAO_PriceFieldValue", NULL, "price_field_id")`

### Why the value is `null` there?

If we look back to line 99 of `PriceField.php`:

```
  $fieldOptions = civicrm_api3('price_field_value', 'get', array(
    'price_field_id' => $priceField->id,
    'sequential' => 1,
  ));
```

And think of the action we, as users, are trying to perform, i.e. editing/adding a new Fee field, the `$fieldOptions['values']` will not contain this new field.

Thus the next and only `foreach` that assigns the options to `$optionsIds` prior to that `elseif` block:

```
foreach ($fieldOptions['values'] as $option) {
  $optionsIds['id'] = $option['id'];
  ...
}
```

Will not not have an iteration for this new field. At the point where `civicrm_api3('price_field_value'` is invoked to get the field associated to an id, since the new field's id does not exist, `null` will show up.

Therefore, this particular `elseif` block should only be run only if the field has an id already associated to it, the `!empty($optionsIds)` condition only prevented part of possible failures in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug (see https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20729) and it is fixed in 4.7.22. If an upgrade is not an option you can manually apply the patch https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20729 .

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10597/files for CRM issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/projects/CRM/issues/CRM-20760

Answer (score 0):

@sovereign108 The [issue on Jira has been updated with a comment](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20729) by @favrik.  The workaround for now is to use price sets, as that is not impacted.